# Slide absolute div with left 120%, to left -10px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to slide an absolute div, with left 120%, to left -10px on button click.

This is what I tried. But it doesn't work.

**jQuery**

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('#window').css('left', '-120%');
    $(this).css('left', '-10px');
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="popular-item">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="button">
            ENTER
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="window"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html body div#main-container div#window {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: -120%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(167,157,157,1);
    background-color: #377bc2;
    border-left: 10px solid #2173AD;
    z-index: 10;
}

html body div#main-container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(167,157,157,0.1);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You're moving two different elements. Besides, where's your `.button` element? You're also over doing it with the CSS selectors, `#main-container` and `#window` should be enough. No need to list all those other elements, that is, unless the rest of your CSS is loaded with heavy selectors.

Comment: There's no CSS for `.button` either.

Comment: I've added the button HTML. I am trying to get it triggered when they click the div class="button"; @hungerstar

Comment: @Borsn yes,but you're targeting **two different** elements in your JS. 1) The `.button` element itself and 2) the `#window` element (at least that's what it's attempting to do). You're looking to move `#window` from `left: 120%` to `left: -10px` correct?

Comment: If you are trying to move `#window` then you'll need to use `-10px` on the first statement. There's no point moving `#window` to `-120%` if it's already there. Unless you moved it before.

Comment: There's also no point in searching for `#window` in `.button` ancestors, it's an id so it should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're asking though I don't think the result is quite what you're expecting:

```js
$( '.button' ).click( function() {
    $( '#window' ).css( 'left', '-10px' );
} );
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4fmbn09/

Comment: What's up with the `in`?

Comment: Haha, have no idea, it's gone now.